# Concatenate multiple xml columntype rows in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have an online form, whereby each entry adds the data as xml to an xml column in SQL.

```
ApplicationID(uniqueidentifier) | DateModified | ApplicationForm(XML)
```

What I need to do is perform a select query that will grab all the ApplicationForm xml values, and concatenate them together to form one result, e.g.

```
Row1: <ApplicationForm type=""></ApplicationForm>
Row2: <ApplicationForm type=""></ApplicationForm>
```

Select result:

```
<Applications>
   <ApplicationForm type=""></ApplicationForm>
   <ApplicationForm type=""></ApplicationForm>
</Applications>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this page](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/), which lists quite a number of ways to concatenate rows of data.

Comment: There's probably a neater way than string concatenation though seeing as the input rows and desired output are both XML.

Comment: Have looked at XML AUTO etc, but the best I can get is <Root><ApplicationForm><ApplicationForm></ApplicationForm></ApplicationForm>. The xml data has the "root" node already, which the column is adding in as well

Comment: @mickyjtwin: In your `FOR XML AUTO`, you could probably add a `, ROOT('Applications')` and thus define what that root node should be called

Comment: @marc_s, yes I have tried that, which is great, but it is the replication of the ApplicationForm elements, as it is written in the original xml value, and it is also the column name. I only need it once.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a better way to do it than this, but I specified the ApplicationForm tag as a tag to be removed, and then stripped it out.

```
DECLARE @a TABLE (ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
                    DateModified DATETIME,
                    ApplicationForm XML)

INSERT INTO @a
        ( ID, DateModified, ApplicationForm )
VALUES  ( NEWID(), -- ID - uniqueidentifier
          '2010-12-07 18:47:36', -- DateModified - datetime
          '<Application><Form>123</Form></Application>'
          ) ,
         ( NEWID(), -- ID - uniqueidentifier
          '2010-12-07 18:47:36', -- DateModified - datetime
          '<Application><Form>456</Form></Application>'
          )             

DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Result = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), ( SELECT ApplicationForm AS "StripTagOut" 
FROM @a 
FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('Applications'), TYPE   ))

SELECT CONVERT(xml, REPLACE(REPLACE(@Result, '</StripTagOut>', ''), '<StripTagOut>', ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

This was an experiment in using XML EXPLICIT which I believe works:

```
SELECT 1 AS Tag,
       NULL AS Parent,
       NULL [Applications!1],
       NULL [ApplicationForm!2!!XMLTEXT]
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS Tag,
       1 AS Parent,
       NULL [Applications!1],
       ApplicationForm [ApplicationForm!2!!XMLTEXT]      
FROM YourTable
FOR XML EXPLICIT
```

For my own gratification, here is the sample script I used

```
CREATE TABLE XmlTest
(
   ApplicationForm xml
)

INSERT INTO XmlTest VALUES ('<ApplicationForm type="a"><SomeTag>SomeContent</SomeTag></ApplicationForm>')
INSERT INTO XmlTest VALUES ('<ApplicationForm type="b"><SomeTag>SomeOtherContent</SomeTag></ApplicationForm>')

SELECT 1 AS Tag,
       NULL AS Parent,
       NULL [Applications!1],
       NULL [ApplicationForm!2!!XMLTEXT]
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS Tag,
       1 AS Parent,
       NULL [Applications!1],
       ApplicationForm [ApplicationForm!2!!XMLTEXT]      
FROM XmlTest       
FOR XML EXPLICIT
```

Which output

```
<Applications>
  <ApplicationForm type="a">
    <SomeTag>SomeContent</SomeTag>
  </ApplicationForm>
  <ApplicationForm type="b">
    <SomeTag>SomeOtherContent</SomeTag>
  </ApplicationForm>
</Applications>
```